# Contract Deployed via Truffle doesn't work, Remix deployed contract does work. Why?

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix, truffle-migration, ganache

So, I am developing (or trying to) with Truffle against ganache.

When I do "truffle migrate" I get:

```
Using network 'development'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Replacing Migrations...
  ... 0x91a36c8c3da5085ea78c09cbbedd41b135c917ff682b64cc521442f24763e9ac
  Migrations: 0xbd2c938b9f6bfc1a66368d08cb44dc3eb2ae27be
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0xae5622d12af119348c09ed0e544d2fd1670096571106c4fd61bb6b8dce8b633f
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Deploying shitlist...
  ... 0xc1a103c54c154947a2e86c77c3a94c1ae8eacf6f173b1a1e66204582b4c6f7fc
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-migrate/index.js:225:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:1)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:132:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:114:19)
```

However, if I dig into Ganache to actually check the last transaction, I see my contract address.

If I plug this contract address into Remix (Which is connected to Ganache as well), it seems as though it's deployed just fine.

So why do I keep getting this error?

EDIT: Actually maybe it doesn't correctly migrate- as the contract does not work as expected. When I Deploy using remix (to the same network), the contract works as expected. The contract which was deployed via Truffle, does not however function, even though I find it in the blockchain.

Thanks!

Comment: Okay in this case, I added waaaayyy more gas when deploying with Truffle and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contract runs out of gas while being deployed I guess.

'Exception while processing transaction: out of gas'

Comment: Thanks, yes this was the problem. I thought I had enough gas, but I needed to add a substantially larger amount of gas.